# How to display 2d array in grid from?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

```
string userName = Console.ReadLine(); 


string[,] stats = new string[5,5];
stats[1,0] = "Name: ";
stats[1,1] = "userName";
```

I know this might not be the most efficient way of doing things but Im new and just playing around with C#. How would I display this? Everytime I try it always displays them on top of eachother.

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? Do you mean printing them to the console? What code have you tried?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

With a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < stats.GetLength(0); i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < stats.GetLength(1); j++)
    Console.Write("{0} ", stats[i, j]);
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Here is a LINQ-based solution:

```
string[,] stats = new string[3,3] {
  { "Name:", "userName", "some stat" },
  { "More stat:", "more", "more" },
  { "Even more:", "hey", "great" }
};
var lines = stats.Cast<string>()
                 .Select((v, i) => new { Idx = i, Val = v })
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Idx / stats.GetLength(1))
                 .Select(x => string.Join(" ", x.Select(y => y.Val)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

Prints

> Name: userName some stat
>
> More stat: more more
>
> Even more: hey great